# How to get notified when DST change happens on android?

Tags: android, timezone, dst

Is there a way to detect DST changes happening?
I tried using a broadcast receiver by TIMEZONE_CHANGED and TIME_SET, but none of them was triggered when the Android system changed DST.
The backup solution is to listen to TIME_TICK and check every single minute to know whether it happened but it does not like a good solution, only for this purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Daylight Saving Time in Android kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818853/daylight-saving-time-in-android-kotlin)

Comment: Thanks, but this not answer my question, I only want to be notified when DST change happened.

Comment: I'm going to assume you've seen: [Date and time change listener in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481386/295004) and [How to detect Daylight Saving Time transition in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36253913/295004) Please realize that linking/mentioning prior questions which you've tried is useful for readers. Also explaining why you need to be notified for a DST change may help provide alternate solutions.